# Finding roots of a List

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I'm having some problems to find the root of an equation, but I'm solving this equation numerically with a list of numbers.
I've got the following equation:

```
f(s)=1-a(s)+2irho(s)b(s)
```

where s is a list of complex numbers in the complex plane.

```
s=List{Re s,Im s}
```

a(s),b(s) and c(s) are also lists of complex numbers.

I have to find the values of s for which

```
f(s[Re s,Im s])==0
```

I've tried using FindRoot, NSolve... but both of them require to have a defined function and not a list of numbers, that's my case. I've also tried to interpolate the list of numbers and trying again with FindRoot or NSolve but they don't seem to work this way.
UPDATE: here's the original code

```
m = 0.13957;
rho[s_] = 
Piecewise[{{Sqrt[1 - 4 m^2/s], Im[s] >= 0}, {-Sqrt[1 - 4 m^2/s], 
 Im[s] < 0}}];
k[s_] := Sqrt[s/4 - m^2];
step = 2/20;
si = Table[(i) step, {i, 1, 21}];
ai[a0_, a1_] = Table[{si[[i]], {a0 + a1 si[[i]]}}, {i, 1, 21}];
im = Table[0, {i, 1, 21}];
tol = 1;
While[tol > 0.001, 
bi[a0_, a1_] = 
Table[ai[a0, a1][[i, 2]], {i, 1, 21}] + 
1/Pi NIntegrate [
Table[si[[i]] im[[i]]/(s (s - si[[i]])), {i, 1, 21}], {s, 4 m^2,
2}, Method -> PrincipalValue, Exclusions -> Thread[si == s], 
AccuracyGoal -> 8];
a[a0_, a1_, b0_] = bi[a0, a1] + I im;
Ima[a0_, a1_, b0_] = 
Table[rho[si[[i]]] b0 (si[[i]] - 4 m^2)^(a0 + a1 si[[i]])/
Abs[Gamma[
a[a0, a1, b0][[i]] + 3/2]] Exp[-a1 si[[
i]] (1 - Log[a1]) + (si[[i]]/
Pi)  NIntegrate[(im[[
i]] Log[(si[[i]] - 4 m^2)/(s - 4 m^2)] + 
Arg[Gamma[a[0.520, 0.902, 0.520][[i]] + 3/2]])/(s (s - 
si[[i]])), {s, 4 m^2, 2}, Method -> PrincipalValue, 
Exclusions -> Thread[si == s], AccuracyGoal -> 8]], {i, 1, 
21}];
tol = Table[Ima[a0, a1, b0][[i]] - im[[i]], {i, 1, 21}];
im = Ima[a0, a1, b0]];

sp = Table[(i step - I i step), {i, 1, 21}];
ialpha[a0_, a1_] = 
Table[a0 + 
a1 sp[[i]] + (sp[[i]]/Pi) NIntegrate[
  Ima[0.520, 0.902, 0.520][[i]]/(s (s - sp[[i]])), {s, 4 m^2, 
   2}], {i, 1, 21}];
beta[a0_, a1_, b0_] = 
Table[Ima[a0, a1, b0][[i, 1]]/rho[sp[[i]]], {i, 1, 21}];

ti[a0_, a1_, b0_] = 
Table[beta[a0, a1, b0][[i]]/(1 - ialpha[a0, a1][[i]]), {i, 1, 21}];
tii[a0_, a1_, b0_] = 
 Table[beta[a0, a1, b0][[
 i]]/(1 - ialpha[a0, a1][[i]] + 
  2 I rho[si[[i]]] beta[a0, a1, b0][[i]]), {i, 1, 21}];
 f[a0_, a1_, b0_] = 
 Table[(1 - ialpha[a0, a1][[i]] + 
 2 I rho[si[[i]]] beta[a0, a1, b0][[i]]), {i, 1, 21}];
 f[0.520, 0.902, 0.520]
```

So, now that I posted the code (I didn't post it before because it's a bit tedious), I want to know for which values of sp (which is a complex number)

```
f[0.520, 0.902, 0.520]==0
```

If anyone could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try `ListInterpolation` to convert the three functions into 2D `InterpolatingFunction`s, to which you then might apply `FindRoot`.  To obtain more concrete advice, provide short versions of your three arrays, `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: You might also use `ListContourPlot` of the real and imaginary parts of `f` to see where the zero-contours of the two intersect.

Comment: you really should use proper mathematica syntax. Its hard to tell if you are posting some sort of pseudocode, or maybe you problem is your syntax is all foobar.  (every single bracket/parenthesis is of the wrong type in your expressions)

Comment: @bbgodfrey I updated my original post with the code. Sorry for the inconvenience. I will try what you said.

Comment: I see the table `f`.  Which quantity in the code is the table `s`?   Is there any reason to compute `ti` and `tii` here?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I just have to find the poles of  `tii`, you don't have to worry about `ti`. The pole condition is `f[a0,a1,b0]==0`. With `a0=0.502, a1=0.902, b0=0.502`. The solution should be that it has a pole at (approximatedly) `sp=0.763-0.073 I` and I don't know how to get to this solution. Thank you.

Comment: it's `sp` I wrote it down incorrectly.

Comment: The list of the imaginary part of the`f` computed by the code is positive for all points, so there is no solution `f == 0`.  Also, I notice that `s` is a straight line.  Is that always true?  If so, the problem is much simpler.

Comment: Okay, it seems I've done something wrong. I'll explain. First I calculated `Ima[a0_, a1_, b0_]` in the real axis of `s` (which i called ´si´). Now I have to extend to extend `s` to the complex plane. To do so, I made a new list, called ´sp´ (I chose it so the pole appear in the negative part of the complex plane `sp=Res-Ims`. With this `sp` I calculated `ialpha[a0_, a1_]`, and then  `beta[a0_, a1_, b0_]`. Now that I've done this, I have to look for the poles of `tii[a0_, a1_, b0_]`, for any `a0,a1,b0`. But I know that for `a0=502, a1=0.902, b0=0.502` there should be a pole in `sp=0.76-0.07 I`.

Comment: To find an approximate pole of `f[s]`, there must be several `s` values in the array that are near the pole.  By the way, why not describe `f` as a continuous function instead of discretizing it with `Table`?  Then, you could use `FindRoot`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.